# What are the insulating properties of wetsuits when worn above water?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, material-science

If I understand correctly, wetsuits insulate their wearers when they are immersed in water. I assume that the same is true when they are not immersed in water (especially when dry); is that true? What major factors affect this?

Comment: Water conducts thermal energy far more than air. The name "wetsuits"  reflects the fact that they provide thermal efficient insulation *even when immersed into water*, unlike your everyday clothing. Just another property is that they don't get "wet", unlike your cotton-wool pullover when you're get caught in the rain.

Comment: Yes, wet suits get really warm really fast when you get back in a boat in the hot sun.

Answer (score 1):

wetsuits are made out of air-filled foam rubber which conducts heat poorly both in water and when dry. What's unique about wetsuits is they allow a little water to leak into them between your skin and the rubber; your body heats up that small amount of water fairly quickly and then the rubber foam inhibits the loss of that heat- so you stay warm even though you are wet.

They stop working when you dive to depths sufficient to compress the air cells in the foam so their volume decreases; this makes them more thermally conductive and you start getting cold.

Comment: I still remember my check out dive in March in upstate New York. 40 degree water, borrowed not-great-fitting wetsuit, just not tight enough around the neck. Every once in a while I'd get a jet of cold water shooting down my spine. Brrrr....

Comment: Thanks @niels nielsen! I will mark this as the answer tomorrow. Do you know of any cheaper material with similar feel and thickness that would insulate to a similar degree when dry?

Comment: there are lots of candidates; look up "thinsulate" (brand name).